# SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB Download Fails

Tags: sql-server-2016-localdb

The download [link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/2/E12B3655-D817-49BA-B934-CEB9DAC0BAF3/SqlLocalDB.msi) for the SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB redistributable (sqllocaldb.msi) is broken.

The link I have been using in the past, that one worked fine. Since there is no bootstrapper package available for SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB in Visual Studio 2015, I created my own using this link. It used to work (most of the time). Now it's completely broken. (See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3e9e48d4-ab33-4b75-95e2-2a6678ee02b9/sql-server-2016-express-localdb-bootstrapper-package-download-fails?forum=sqlexpress&prof=required) on msdn forum)

Also the download link in the topic "SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB" is also broken.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have also posted this on Microsoft Connect - SQL Server.

Comment: By the way, I'm referring to a bootstrapper package in the question above.Thanks.

Comment: Also, this download URL is no longer working at all. If URL is entered directly into the browser address, it starts the download but then fails.